# Local inner class in Java

Tags: java, inner-classes

For the below code sample, when we execute the code it will print:

> from instance method
>   from local inner class

Now, what if I only want to only execute the local inner class method m2() and wants the output as:

> from local inner class

```
class A {
    void m1() {
        class B {
            void m2() {
                System.out.println("from local inner class");
            }
        }
        System.out.println("from instance method");
        B b = new B();
        b.m2();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A a = new A();
        a.m1();
    }
}
```

And what exactly the use case when local inner class is absolutely needed without which some functionality may not gets implemented.

Comment: If you only want to execute one `println` then... err... remove the other one?

Comment: I am wondering, is there a way to only execute m2() ?

Comment: The idea of something being local to a method is that it should be used only from within that method. Hence if you want to call `m2` from outside `m1`, why make `B` local to `m1`?

Comment: "I am wondering, is there a way to only execute m2() ?" Technically, yes. You can make `m1` return an `Object` of `B` and then use reflection to call `m2` outside `m1`, I think.

Comment: m2 is not visible outside of m1 method. to execute only m2 add a boolean parameter to m1 method and use an if statement to decide if only m2 needs to be executed or the entire m1

Answer (score 1):

I cannot see what you are driving at, maybe you want to split the creation of the method from the invocation of the method, hiding all the implementation details in an inner class? If so how about this....

First create an interface so you know what type you are accessing (tidier than reflection)

```
interface X {
    void m2()
}
```

Now the method m1() returns an instance of class implementing interface

```
class A {
    X m1() {
        class B {
            void m2() {
                System.out.println("from local inner class");
            }
        }
        B b = new B();
        return b;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A a = new A();
        // call m1() to get an instance of interface X
        X x = a.m1();
        // invoke method on interface instance
        x.m2()
    }
}
```

This has split the creation of the method (wrapped in a class, think 'functor') from the invocation of the method.

Answer (score 0):

You can return objects of local class type from a function and invoke methods on them via reflection, e.g. the following works:

```
class A {
    Object m1() {
        class B {
            public void m2() {
                System.out.println("from local inner class");
            }
        }
        System.out.println("from instance method");
        B b = new B();
        b.m2();
        return b;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            A a = new A();
            Object obj = a.m1();
            obj.getClass().getMethod("m2").invoke(obj);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.toString());   
        }   
    }
}
```

Should you do this? Probably not.